# why does not ruby support symbols that includes operators?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

My question why does not ruby support symbols that includes operators(what is the idea behind it)?

example like

```
attr_accessor :active?
```

on the contrary

it supports

```
  :@user
```

but not

```
  :user@
```

Comment: you should help parser to understand you, I believe, `:"user@"`?

Comment: @fl00r, that's ok, but could you write brief explanation of the above, and the resources through which i can understand the parser?

Comment: Sachin, if want to understand in detail how Ruby's parser works, and, more generally, what's happening under the hood (aka bonnet), I can recommend [this book](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope).

Comment: Yes..that book is dedicated for Ruby internals

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "operator", but all of your examples are clearly valid `Symbol`s:

```
:active?
'active?'.to_sym
:'active?'
```

and

```
'user@'.to_sym
:'user@'
```

are perfectly valid `Symbol`s. `Symbol`s can even contain whitespace as well as any Unicode character imaginable:

```
'        '.to_sym
:'        '
```

Comment: does :'active?' looks better or :active? ?

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?